# ES6 Using Export And Import Got An Error

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I want to use the function in another JS file, so I do this:

a.js

```
const GotMsg = {
    test1(key) {
        console.warn(`It is Test1 + ${key}`);
    },
    test2(key) {
        console.warn(`It is Test2 + ${key}`);
    },
};
```

b.js

```
import * as test from 'scripts/a'
const result = test.GotMsg.test1('AA');
console.log(result);
```

And run in Chrome, but I got an error in Chrome developer tool:

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read property 'test1' of
>   undefined
>       at eval

How sould I do to solve the error?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for that error is because you are not importing it correctly and you also did not export default `GotMsg`.

```
// a.js
const GotMsg = {
  test1(key) {
    console.warn(`It is Test1 + ${key}`);
  },
  test2(key) {
    console.warn(`It is Test2 + ${key}`);
  },
};
export default GotMsg;

// b.js
import GotMsg from './scripts/a';

const result = GotMsg.test1('AA');
console.log(result);
```

Or you can export it like this:

```
// a.js
export const GotMsg = {
  test1(key) {
    console.warn(`It is Test1 + ${key}`);
  },
  test2(key) {
    console.warn(`It is Test2 + ${key}`);
  },
};

// b.js
import { GotMsg } from './scripts/a';
```

Comment: Excuse me. I would like to know why I can't use "import * as test from 'scripts/a'" in b.js?

Comment: You should be able to do that. `export const GotMsg` like that. Doing that imports everything that was exported in a.js as `test`

Comment: OK, I see. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You're not exporting GotMsg in a.js

```
const GotMsg = {
  test1(key) {
    console.warn(`It is Test1 + ${key}`);
  },
  test2(key) {
    console.warn(`It is Test2 + ${key}`);
  },
};
export default GotMsg;
```

Then in b.js

```
import GotMsg from './GotMsg'; // or wherever it is

// do things.
```

Another way of exporting would be to export each individual function

```
export function test1() {}
export function test2() {}
```

Then

```
import { test1, test2 } from './path/to/file';
```

Comment: That's it, you cannot import a package of code if you haven't previously exported ^^

Comment: Oh! I don't know why it doesn't display. I just type "export default {GotMsg};" in the a.js end. If it shouldnt't use the"{}" in export?

Comment: @Mark shouldn't use `{}` in the export unless you're exporting an object. If you do so, then your import changes as well. `import { GotMsg } from './GotMsg';` _should_ work.

Comment: I understand now. Thank you.